# Exporting from Inkscape to LaTeX - via TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, workflow, inkscape

I know only the very basics of TikZ, having only used it to produce a pretty flow chart for one of my documents. I recently learned that you can use Inkscape and export to TikZ.

What are the limitations of the Inkscape->TikZ workflow? Is there some compelling reason to take the time to learn TikZ (which I'm told has a fairly steep learning curve) rather than simply exporting to TikZ from Inkscape?

Comment: You might wish to take a look at `TikZiT`, http://tikzit.sourceforge.net.

Comment: I'd guess that the TikZ code produced by Inkscape is 'messier' than hand written code, relying mostly/only on absolute positioning, perhaps making adjustments more difficult. But I've never really used that route a lot, so I'm not that familiar with it.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. From what I've seen of the code produced by Inkscape this definitely seems correct. I'd be curious to know (though don't expect you to have an answer since you say you haven't used Inkscape->TikZ much) if this is an issue if you're content to modify your graphics within Inkscape.

Comment: `tikz` isn't that difficult (not like PSTricks) IMO. You have an excellent manual too. In `inkscape` you have to draw using mouse and accuracy of putting some thing *here* will be lost.

Comment: I'm curious. Why not go directly from inkscape to TeX?

Comment: @EthanBolker Is that an option? I'm very new to using graphics in LaTeX--- I've almost exclusively used it to typeset text. Is the suggestion to simply generate an image with Inkscape and then directly include that image in your .tex (as opposed to exporting to TikZ first)?

Comment: @HarishKumar What makes me hesitant to spend the time learning it is how little need I have for graphics in my documents. I'd need to generate _maybe_ 5-6 diagrams per year and don't necessarily want to spend a lot of time generating them. Your second point is something I'd be worried about, though. What sort of accuracy do you lose? Is the accuracy within Inkscape the issue (e.g., if there was no way to pull up a grid and use a combo of the mouse and coordinates to ensure accurate placement of items)? Or is the issue with accuracy once you export to TikZ and include the code in your .tex?

Comment: UPDATE 2020: The `TikZiT` project is now hosted on GitHub: https://tikzit.github.io/

Comment: (alternative programs such as TikZIt can be found at [editors - What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz) instead.)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Edit:** @XiaodongQi comments below that

> The same options are no longer available in the newer version of
>   Inkscape. But there are similar options when saving the PDF.

You can save your inkscape figures as pdfs and put them in your document with `\includegraphics`. If you have text in your figures you can select the PDF+LaTeX option from the inkscape save-as pdf menu. That will create a pdf_tex file instead. You `\input` that file and TeX does the typesetting.

In inkscape:

[image]

Saving from inkscape after selecting save-as pdf. Inkscape writes file `topview.pdf_tex`:

[image]

In the document:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering{
\resizebox{75mm}{!}{\input{images/topview.pdf_tex}}
\caption{Top view.}
\label{fig:topView}
}
\end{figure}
```

Output:

[image]

This is clearly a picture that could be drawn with tikz, but I chose not to, for reasons you spelled out in your response to @HarishKumar - the longer tikz learning curve and a preference for wysiwyg for occasional use. If you did need precise placement (lines really meeting at corners) you might be able to do that with the snap-to features of inkscape. I haven't tried those yet.

Comment: When you expand it, if you could note whether this approach would have shortcomings compared to a pure TikZ approach that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so you can't directly make a pdf with equations from inkscape in MAC?

Comment: @CharlieParker You may be able to write equations in inkscape (I don't know). The point of the PDF+LaTeX option is to have TeX typeset the text in the figure (whether or not it's mathematical) so that the fonts and typography match those in the surrounding document.

Comment: The same options are no longer available in the newer version of Inkscape. But there are similar options when saving the PDF.

Comment: I needed to add \usepackage{graphicx} to make this work (it fails if you use graphics)

Comment: While the export in itself works, all my text is misaligned. It seems Inkscape and Latex position the boxes differently, with Latex not being able to center the text as intended.

Comment: Instead of opening Inkscape, one [can also use the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62492861/4027729).

Answer (score 29):

After exporting (described by Ethan Bolker) use the following snippet to embed the image generated by Inscape:

```
\begin{figure}
\def\svgwidth{\linewidth}
\input{img/filename.pdf_tex}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

Using `\def\svgwidth{desired width}` instead of `\resizebox` will **preserve the font size**. This is the recommended way described in the head of the generated file:

```
%% Creator: Inkscape 0.91_64bit, www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file '_masks.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Rather than code snippets it's better to give a compilable [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: thanks for the links/suggestions. I tried to post it as comment to the answer above, but I do not have enough karma.

Comment: When I do this all my text looks out of place + incorrect size. Any tips?

Comment: I needed to add \usepackage{graphicx} to make this work (it fails if you use graphics)

Comment: @JuanLeni I use the latex font (CMU serif) in Inkscape (with same size and \baselineskip as in the document) and get very accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

As another alternative, there is a tool [SVG2TikZ](http://xyz2tex.github.io/svg2tikz/) (used to be Inkscape2TikZ), which can be used to generate TikZ code.

If you install the Python package from the GitHub repository, you can convert a SVG (which may be exported from Inkscape) to TeX source code using TikZ as follows:

```
svg2tikz a.svg > a.tex
```

It can also be installed as a Inkscape extension.