# Latex text quality + font in a drawing tool

Tags: fonts, graphics

I use CorelDraw on a Windows platform and would like to get the latex PDF-text quality + font in a certain drawing.

What is the best approach?

- print the text as pdf via latex first and then copy-paste part of a screenprint?
- I installed Latin Modern Roman fonts for Windows that are "equal" to latex fonts but there is a big difference visisble, especially after zooming in, the latex fonts are perfectly sharp, the other fonts become fuzzy bitmaps.
- other possibilities?

EDIT: I made the error to not select the `commercial printing' option, when exporting the drawing for desktop applications. The use of latin modern fonts now gives a better result.  It looks somewhat more gray, but it is acceptable.

Comment: I know nothing about coraldraw but it is a vector program so it presumably shouldn't need bitmap fonts but impossible to say why you are seeing that (and it's likely off topic for this site) similarly to transfer a latex generated pdf you are likely to be better to import the pdf into coraldraw directly as a scalable image rather than use a screendump bitmap of the latex rendering/

Comment: Latin Modern are available as opentype (and included in TeX Live in this format, as well as type1). I don't know what 'Latin Modern Roman fonts for Windows' would be other than just Latin Modern Roman opentype.

Comment: Uhm... perhaps a vector program such as Corol Draw or Adobe Illustrator won't get you the best quality of text. In my own experience I prefer InDesign, although for create a flyer or poster. I work in layers, the illustration part in Illustrator i.e. and later all the final arrangement I do it in InDesign.

I don't think you'll need the `LaTeX` fonts in Corel for get the same quality, because you need to compose with the same Quality and the vector programs has not so good tools for that.

Comment: But if you need to use a vector program with LaTeX, the your choice is Inkscape that has a plugin for create vectorial draws compatible with TeX and Tikz.

Comment: The answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz/151287#151287 describes @Aradnix solution.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well what you need,  it's a way to have LaTeX-formatted text in CorelDraw graphics. Probably you should use the `psfragger` utility, as it seems to be dedicated to such a job. From the readme file that comes with it:

> PSFragger is a free tool used to replace some labels in eps files  by
>   using psfrag and LaTeX. The result is modified eps file that can  be
>   further converted to PDF file for use with PDFLaTeX (eps to pdf
>   conversion  is included in this tool).  Use of Ghostscript is assumed
>   a priori.
>   It's available on CTAN.

Alternatively, you include your graphic file in a LaTEX document, and use the `psfrag` or `psfragx` package, to replace the CorelDraw-generated text by a LaTeX formatted one and export the result as an .eps or .pdf file.

Comment: Interesting, but too involved for me to use.

Answer (score 2):

My answer may not be relevant, the version of Corel I used was CorelDraw 11, and it was a few years ago. I used to compile my text with LaTeX to produce a `dvi` file, and then use `dvi2ps` to produce a postscript version. The postscript file was then opened with Corel, and the option `import text as curves` was chosen. It is then possible to copy and paste the text, and move the text to your graphic as you wish. The "text" is no longer editable as text in the normal way though. The latest version of Corel is x6 (corel 16) and I don't have access to that.