# Illustrator export for Latex

Tags: graphics, pdf, illustrator, export

I'm currently searching for a way of creating pictures for a LaTeX document.

Currently I'm trying to create the pictures with Adobe Illustrator, but I've got no clue how to import them in an good way to LaTeX?

At least I'm looking for an way of creating fine texts (so sizes and fonts are managed within the LaTeX document).

> Is there a way to do it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 4):

You can export them in any format you want that is understood by Inkscape and doesn't destroy the text information. So no export to any pixel format like png or jpg.

Then you can import your image in Inkscape and export it as "PDF+LaTeX":

> From version 0.48, Inkscape has a special PDF+LaTeX output option. All lines and shapes are saved into a PDF file, while all texts are saved into a LaTeX file. Compiling this LaTeX will give you back the whole drawing.

From [here](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/LaTeX). This way, all your fonts should be set to your document font.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz/151287#151287

Comment: Juri my experience with this is that the resulting pdf does not work correctly in all pdf viewers (not even in preview on osx). So doing that might make it difficult for reviewers to access your document and thus frustrate them.

Comment: I didn't have that experience with any Windows viewer I tried. I think I tested with Adobe, foxit and Sumatra.

Comment: Reviewers may not be using Windows, however .... So it would be good to know if it isn't a good cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting to SVG format will help to preserve all data intact, then add it directly to LateX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!