# Inkscape image only partially rendered

Tags: graphics, inkscape

I have an Inkscape image, saved as a PDF, that I am inserting into a .tex document. I am experience some strange rendering issues. Here is my code (the image is saved as D3.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{D3}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Here is a screenshot of what the image is *supposed* to look like:
[image]

Here is what it looks like when I open the pdf output of the compiled .tex file in Preview on my Mac:
[image]

I have tried saving the picture as pdf+latex in Inkscape, but it doesn't change anything. I have tried changing the size of the picture in the .tex file. This causes some things to look different. For example one or two nodes will appear or some small arc of one of the ovals. But it still doesn't render completely.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Side note: When I open the document on my PC, it renders fine. However, when I open the pdf (compiled from the .tex file), the image doesn't appear all at once. It seems to "load" in pieces (first the dots, then lines, then ovals, etc...). This is eventually going in a beamer presentation and so having it load this way is still problematic. But I would really like to get it fixed on the Mac, since I don't know if I will have access to a PC when I give the presentation.

Edit: Here are links to [PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6nmzljdzqv7uhup/D3.pdf?dl=0) and [SVG](https://www.dropbox.com/s/knw3z6sjsuegmka/D3.svg?dl=0) files for the image.

Comment: Without the image file, it is going to be hard to say anything other than 'there is a problem with the image file'. The slowness is possibly due to the size of the file but beyond that....

Comment: @cfr The .svg file is 15kb and the .pdf is 32kb. When you say "without the image file", are you suggesting that I provide some further information about the image? If so, can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you post it somewhere and provide a link?

Comment: Ok, I am not sure if this works, but I am adding some links in the body of the question.

Comment: Works fine here with your file(s). But, in the svg and pdf you have uploaded, the lines between the ellipses are not there. Other than that, the compiled pdf from pdflatex shows the figure as expected.

Comment: @mas Darn, sorry. I fixed it. I really have several pictures that I am using in sequence and this is happening with all of them. Are you experiencing the "slow loading" issue where it sort of appears in pieces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try different approach: Export the `svg` into `TikZ`. See [Exporting from Inkscape to LaTeX - via TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz) That way the pdf would be created by LaTeX compiler and not by Inkscape, and so it might render faster (I never had loading performance problems with TikZ drawings even if they were quite complex).

Comment: This did work better, but I am still experiencing a delay in loading the image (on a PC) and pieces of the image are missing (on the Mac). I would think that its a problem with my computer, but it's strange that it's happening on both.