# Inkscape unable to render latex text

Tags: windows, vector, inkscape, rendering

I am trying to render some Latex text in Inkscape on Windows, but I keep getting the error

```
Problem during opening C:\Program Files\pstoedit\drvmagick.dll:
Unable to find the specified module.
```

I have already installed pstoedit and the file drvmagick.dll is exactly in that directory (which I also added to the PATH).

Comment: This may help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz/151287#151287

Comment: I never knew that you can somehow compile LaTeX code »in« Inkscape. Could you describe detailed, what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will check it out.

I am trying to insert latex text in inkscape and I know that on Linux there is available the option Extension -> Render -> Latex which allows you to complile some code and get a vector element as output. Unfortunately I do not have a Linux system available now...

Answer (score 3):

So basically you are seeing this error while trying to use laTeX to add a formula or text to your drawing. as explained in [this page](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/LaTeX) you go to Extensions->Render->LaTeX. but the same error happened on windows 10 and Inkscape 0.92:

[image]

Doing some search I found [this post in Inkscape forums](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=4937). There several possible soloutions have been proposed, but the one which worked for me was to delete the faulty file:

> drvmagick.dll

and it now works just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will check if this works for me, unfortunately I do not have Inkscape at hand now...

Comment: NP, just give it a try and let me know if it did work or not.

Comment: The forum link is not working

Comment: @jperezmartin sorry I don't know what is wrong with the Inkscape forum!