# Tools with Nice User Interface to Create Block Diagrams in TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing, tools, block

I know I can use Tikz and insert the source code in TeX. But is there a better way to do it which has a better user interface?

Comment: I do *not* think that this question is Lyx-specific at the moment. I change the tags -- feel free to undo it if you disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LyX has good integration with Dia. Go to Insert > File > External Material and change the template to "Dia diagram". It is nice to have the integration because LyX knows how to convert a Dia diagram on the fly. So if you edit a .dia file you don't have to remember to re-export it to the corresponding format (because LyX does this automatically for you).

So you can just include a Dia diagram in LyX. And anytime you want, just right-click and go to "Edit Externally". When you save your edits from Dia, everything is taken care of.

Another advantage is that there is a preview in LyX of what your .dia diagram is.

Answer (score 5):

You can use any tool with a graphical user interface and export an image file for use in LaTeX (and LyX). An example is [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/download/), available for Windows/Mac/Linux, which can be used for [block diagrams](http://www.ioncannon.net/utilities/123/10-tips-for-creating-good-looking-diagrams-using-inkscape/). Export to `.eps` or `.pdf` for good results in print and when zoomed. Inkscape also has a nice feature to [export to LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151287/89417), which means that you can use LaTeX symbols, consistent fonts, etc. in your diagram.

Some more options, (including Tikz-related tools), are mentioned in [What GUI applications are there to assist in generating graphics for TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26972/89417) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ#External_links.

Answer (score 4):

*This is an addition to the already good answer of [Marijn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/89417/marijn).*

### Direct answer to your question

Maybe have a look at **[TikzEdt](http://www.tikzedt.org)**. TikzEdt is a combined WYSIWYG/text editor designed for editing Tikz code [taken from the website].

### Indirect answer to your question

Also, you can use other tools like **Microsoft Visio** (offline) or **[draw.io](https://www.draw.io/)** (online).

The already mentioned **similar question**: [What GUI applications are there to assist in generating graphics for TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972) leads to more tools:

- [Dia](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Dia/)
- [Ipe](http://ipe.otfried.org/)
- [Xfig](http://mcj.sourceforge.net/)
- [LaTeXDraw](http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/)