# Saving an SVG image to TeX code in Inkscape

Tags: graphics, pstricks, svg, inkscape

I'm trying to export a SVG file into TeX code (pstricks) using Inkscape. I've created the code but I think something is missing in the preamble. What packages should I use? And what is the proper name to enter in the documentclass?
I'm adding the screenshot of all the errors which have occurred.
[image: Screenshoot]

Because my code is too long I decided to upload it using a link:
[link to my .tex file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_vodv0yPKLRT245WUo2U1FIekU)

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't export directly to `.pdf`?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I have to create a .tex file @Bernard

Comment: @Bernard perhaps LaTeX -> dvi -> ps. While Inkscape can export eps (or you can convert) I've had trouble in the past.

Comment: @Hendrra: Sure, but then you use `\includegraphics`. I mentioned this possibility because the pstricks code produced by all these graphic programs is not very good.

Comment: @Chris: With Inkscape you can *save* as .pdf. I didn't use this possibility very often, but I never had any problem.

Comment: @Bernard Where should I use \includegraphics? Is it important to save that SVG image in the folder where I have my .tex file?

Comment: `\includegraphics{mygraphicfile}` is used in the .tex file at the place where you want it (or you preferably let it float  iserting it in a `figure` environment. Another solution would be to use one of  `svg` or `svg-inkscape` packages.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate, possibly helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz/151287#151287

Comment: @Bernard yes, I use pdf from Inkscape all the time. I mean the OP might not be in a position to use pdf at all.

Answer (score 6):

The documentclass is up to you. For pstricks you need the package `pstricks`. If you compile with `pdflatex` you should also load `auto-pst-pdf`.

Don't forget do add the `document` environment as suggested by your editor.

Comment: Now there are no errors but there is only a blank pdf file when I open it.

Comment: Thank you for another advice! How can I do it?

Comment: Is it possible to add many lines of code using {}?

Comment: @Hendrra See [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1193/117534) on how to properly format your code (multi-lined).

Comment: Unfortunately my code was too long so I added a link directly to it.

Comment: @Hendrra Well, for me your code compiles. Workflow: `latex drawing.tex`, `dvips drawing.tex`, `ps2pdf drawing.tex`. If you want to use `pdflatex` please use `auto-pst-pdf` as mentioned (guides are available on this site).

Comment: @TeXnician it compiles and there is the image of the owl? That's strange! Thank you for your help and I'll try to use your tips

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=0.2pt}

.. the rest of your code ...

\end{document}
```

and then run it with `xelatex` or the sequence `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`. If you have still problems paste the complete code into your question as text and not as an image.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I still have some problems with that code. I posted a link to my .tex file.

Comment: instead of your given `\psset` use `\psset{unit=0.2pt}`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Unfortunately there are still some errors: "Undefined control sequence". Have your code worked? How to run it using xelatex?

Comment: I suppose you run your document with `pdf latex` instead of `xelatex` or the sequence latex->dvips->ps2pdf.