# Creating this vectorised watermark in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, watermark

I found this wave like image on [Vecteezy](http://vecteezy.com/):

[image]

I would like to create a similar watermark in colour using TikZ as an interesting pursuit. However, I am unsure on where to start.  Any approach would be appreciated but I would favour updating the `\tikzset` to achieve this. The [Tikx examples website](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) do not contain an example for working with watermarks.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Open in Inkscape, [export as TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232).  Also http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Same method as @percusse, but with three families and opacity. In the original image we can see small variations of the line width, which are not easy to obtain in tikz (but if you really want them you can fill between a pair of close paths).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[opacity=.35]
    \clip (1,-5) rectangle (11,1);
    \foreach \x in {0,0.05,...,2}{
      \draw (0,\x) .. controls (4-\x,-4-3*\x) and (11-2*\x,4-3*\x) .. (12,-5+3*\x);
      \draw (0,\x-1) .. controls (4-\x,\x-2) and (11-2*\x,-4-3*\x) .. (12,-3+3*\x);
      \draw (0,\x-3) .. controls (4-\x,\x-2) and (11-4*\x,-1-4*\x) .. (12,-5+3.5*\x);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ha much better, will delete mine.

Comment: @percusse This makes me regret plagiarizing you:(

Comment: Ahah, why? It is clearly better :)

Comment: @percusse The idea is the same, but I have spent more time on it ... so not very interesting !

Comment: Think of it as getting out of your way for your efforts. No harm is done.

Comment: Excelent!, I add colors using `[count=\n]` and put in `\draw[blue!\n!red!80]`, and it looks awesome, maybe you could add more colorfull presentation in your answer...

Comment: @JLeonV. It's a good idea : feel free to post an answer (based on this one if you want) with colors.

Comment: For variable line width, try the calligraphy tikz library.

Comment: Very good for your wonderful explanation and the code. +1.

Answer (score 19):

Here's an adaptation of the answer from Kpym which adds variable line widths via the [`calligraphy`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) TikZ library.  (In actual fact, in devising this I discovered a bug in said library so this requires the latest version which is on [github](https://github.com/loopspace/spath3) - download `spath3.dtx` and run `tex spath3.dtx` to generate the files).

```
\documentclass{article}
% \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427775/86}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \SPathSplit { m m m m }
{
  \spath_get:nnN {#2} {path} \l__tmpa_tl
  \spath_split_curve:nVNN {#1} \l__tmpa_tl \l__tmpb_tl \l__tmpc_tl
  \spath_clear_new:n {#3}
  \spath_clear_new:n {#4}
  \spath_put:nnV {#3} {path} \l__tmpb_tl
  \spath_put:nnV {#4} {path} \l__tmpc_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\tikzset{save as spath/.code={%
    \tikz@addmode{%
      \pgfsyssoftpath@getcurrentpath\spath@tmp@path%
      \MakeSPath{#1}{\spath@tmp@path}%
    }%
  },%
  restore spath/.code={%
    \SPathInfoInto{#1}{minbb}{\spath@tmp@pt}%
    \expandafter\pgfqpoint\spath@tmp@pt
    \pgf@protocolsizes\pgf@x\pgf@y
    \SPathInfoInto{#1}{maxbb}{\spath@tmp@pt}%
    \expandafter\pgfqpoint\spath@tmp@pt
    \pgf@protocolsizes\pgf@x\pgf@y
    \SPathInfoInto{#1}{path}{\spath@tmp@path}%
    \pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\spath@tmp@path
  },
  heavy line width=.8pt,
  light line width=.1pt,
  line cap=butt
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\pen (0,0);
\clip (1,-5) rectangle (11,1);
\foreach[count=\n] \x in {0,0.05,...,2}{
  \tikzset{every path/.style={blue!\n!red!80},pen colour=blue!\n!red!80}
  \begin{scope}[opacity=.35,transparency group]
  \path[save spath=curve] (0,\x) .. controls (4-\x,-4-3*\x) and (11-2*\x,4-3*\x) .. (12,-5+3*\x);
  \SPathSplit{1/2}{curve}{first}{last}
  \SPathSplit{1/2}{first}{first}{middle}
  \draw[ultra thin, restore spath=first];
  \calligraphy[heavy, restore spath=middle];
  \draw[ultra thin, restore spath=last];
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[opacity=.35,transparency group]
  \path[save spath=curve] (0,\x-1) .. controls (4-\x,\x-2) and (11-2*\x,-4-3*\x) .. (12,-3+3*\x);
  \SPathSplit{3/4}{curve}{first}{last}
  \SPathSplit{3/4}{last}{middle}{last}
  \draw[ultra thin, restore spath=first];
  \calligraphy[heavy, restore spath=middle];
  \draw[ultra thin, restore spath=last];
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[opacity=.35,transparency group]
  \path[save spath=curve] (0,\x-3) .. controls (4-\x,\x-2) and (11-4*\x,-1-4*\x) .. (12,-5+3.5*\x);
  \SPathSplit{1/4}{curve}{first}{last}
  \SPathSplit{2/3}{last}{middle}{last}
  \draw[ultra thin, restore spath=first];
  \calligraphy[heavy, restore spath=middle];
  \draw[ultra thin, restore spath=last];
  \end{scope}


}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Using the `spath3` package we split each curve and then using the `calligraphy` library we thicken one segment (tapering nicely, of course).  The `opacity` key needed moving to the transparency groups because each path is no longer a single one but several spliced together and with just standard opacity, that becomes visible.

I've also added the colours as J Leon V suggested.

[image: watermark]

Comment: Very good. I like also your picture. +1.

Comment: You can probably vary the pen orientation and/or size (in a non linear way) to have not so regular thickened area?

Comment: @Kpym Yes.  Looking at the original then not every line gets the thickened part, so you could switch it off for some lines, or shift it for others.  I just went for the simplest as a proof of concept.  The bit which determines where the thickening part is the number given to `\SPathSplit`.

Comment: @LoopSpace where can I find how to use `spath3` ? The documentation is written more like "code comments". Is it there some doc addressed to the final user that explains what we can do and how we can use this library (with examples) ?

Comment: @Kpym Not really.  I wrote it as a utility to help me with writing other packages.  There are quite a few examples on this site.  If you are serious about wanting to learn to use it, I'd be happy to help (and I could develop that into documentation).  One option would be to start a chat room.  Another would be to email me directly (texdoc tikzmark has my current email address).

Comment: @LoopSpace Thanks for your answer, I understand very well that you have done this as a tool and writing a full documentation is beyond your original motivation. To be honest I don't know if I want to learn it, because I don't know what `spath3` is capable off;) Very often I'm frustrated that in TikZ we don't treat paths as objects : add them, subtract them, take the interior of a path inside another and so on ... Is it `spath3` capable of this kind of things ? Today I used your library to answer [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/428270) without knowing exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: @Kpym The lack of documentation is a definite lack and I ought to write something decent - just need a bit of motivation.  So someone wanting to learn would be a good motivator.  I wrote it so that I could do what you say: treat paths as objects.  It might not be capable of what you say, but because I haven't needed to do that and so haven't added that capability.  I'm open to extending it, or it being extended, as well.  My goal with all my code is that it be useful.

Comment: @LoopSpace this is very promising ! May be a cheatsheet, and/or few examples will be a good start. Thanks again for your volunteer spirit !