# Using Inkscape-generated figures in LaTeX document: How to make process more efficient?

Tags: graphics, subfiles, inkscape, directory

I use LaTeX to type up lecture notes for math and physics, and I use Inkscape whenever I need to generate graphics for them. I want to find a faster method for doing this. Currently, I do the following:

- My files are organized using the `subfiles` package. Each lecture gets its own "individual file", and I compile all of them in one big "master file" via the `subfile` command. This makes the files easier to organize since each TeX file is very short. I organize the "individual files" in a different file than my "master file".
- When I need to generate diagrams, I generate a TikZ file using Inkscape (as discussed for instance in [Ethan Bolker's answer in Exporting from Inkscape to LaTeX - via TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz)) and then include this in my "individual file."

The above method works fine, but there are some aspects that need improvement.

My question:

- When I generate my `.pdf_tex` file, the TikZ command always gives the filename by not the location of the file. (See example below.) I want Inkscape to automatically fill these in with the location of my file. So, for a file `drawing.pdf_tex` located at `/Users/admin/Desktop/` generated by Inkscape file `drawing.svg`, I would like my file to automatically say `/Users/admin/Desktop/drawing.pdf_tex` rather than `<filename>.pdf`.

The reason I need to specify the location of my files in the above manner is because my "individual file" is in a different folder than my "master file," so even if the TikZ compiles in the "individual file," it does not compile in the "master file" unless I specify the location.

Here is a sample of what I get when I compile `drawing.svg` as as a TikZ file:

```
%% Creator: Inkscape inkscape 0.92.2, www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'drawing.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{618.84102366bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.43735005)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{drawing.pdf}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

Answer (score 1):

As of version `v1.4 2019/10/25` of the [`subfiles` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles), there should be no need anymore to specify an extra path. If the subfile finds all files, then the main file loading it via `\subfile` will also find them. This is at least true for files included via `\input` or `\includegraphics`. In the following setup both files, `main.tex` and `sub.tex`, compile.

```
% Structure:
% main.tex
% personalstyle.sty
% subdir/sub.tex
% subdir/image.pdf
% subdir/tikzimage.tex

% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{personalstyle}
\usepackage{subfiles} % Should be loaded last in the preamble!
\begin{document}
\subfile{subdir/sub}
\end{document}

% subdir/sub.tex
\documentclass[../main]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{image.pdf}
\input{tikzimage}
\end{document}
```