Turning Adobe Reader into an interactive picture editor?
The animate package has shown me that interaction via javascript in PDFs is possible.  I would like a WYSIWYG / GUI for editing picture environments, in particular the coordinates of \put directives.  Is it possible to make an editablepicture environment that (1) emits the both the source code and rendered picture (this I can probably figure out how to do with CollArgs or the verbatim package or similar), (2) inserts javascript that makes all of the objects in the picture draggable, and (3) updates the source code output on every mouseup to have the new coordinates of the dragged \put object?
(I'm interested in the picture environment in particular because that's what Inkscape export emits, so that's what I'm starting from.)
(Note that I'd be quite interested in any GUI / WYSIWYG editor/workflow that can edit picture environments, though I wouldn't necessarily consider such a comment an answer to the question as asked, which I'm independently curious about.)

I do find it highly improbable that inkscape exports into a picture environment. Perhaps you mean pspicture?

Or tikzpicture? I know Inkscape can export tikz code.

@UlrikeFischer if inkscape can not export to picture mode, how would it be able to export such works of art as this to latex? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114783/draw-an-aircraft-with-tikz/114847#114847

@DavidCarlisle I thought that was handdrawn by a great artist.

if you want an interactive dragable editor that can export to picture mode look at xfig

@UlrikeFischer The process described at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151287/2066 emits a .pdf file with all of the graphics, and a .pdf_tex file with something like \begin{picture}(1,0.39732546) where everything in the picture is \put(x, y){...} and the ... is either text inside a \makebox(0,0)[lt]{...\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{l}...\end{tabular}}} or a \includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=...]{....pdf}

Picture environmentw, not so much.  Standalone pdf files, try GIMP (for example).

I wonder if stamps could be used to do this, a la https://mirror.las.iastate.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mkstmpdad/doc/mkstmpdad_man.pdf.  Does one really need distiller to create stamps?

Why not just use a grid? I can't imagine that dragging things in the PDF is going to be less work than reading off grid coordinates. What am I missing? And obviously you don't need distiller or Adobe for stamps. If you did nobody on Linux would be able to use them at all. But AcroTeX relies heavily on distiller, as I understand it. (Or did anyway.)

My hope is that I don't have to copy/paste/type grid coordinates.  It takes maybe 1--5 seconds to switch apps and type or copy/paste coordinates.  If I have thirty or forty items, this time adds up, especially because matching up the ordering in the TeX with the PDF adds more overhead.  The interface I'm imagining is that, after dragging all the stamps around (which will maybe take 10% longer per item than reading off the coordinates), I can then copy paste the entire TeX source into my document (which I expect will decrease time by 50%--80%)

@cfr btw, on the topic of stamps, maybe you have insight or an answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/719516/custom-appearances-on-pdf-annotation-stamps-without-acrobat-distiller-with-pdf ?

Well, but the entire TeX source isn't in the PDF. As a general rule, source is discarded. I know there's some work which is aimed at keeping structural elements and, possibly, some markup for, for instance, mathematics, for accessibility reasons, so theoretically you might be able to map those elements back. But that's very much a work-in-progress and I don't know it is likely to support recreating the source of a picture. In general, pictures need alt text - the source wouldn't be any more useful to screen-reading software, for example, than it is to a sighted reader.

Isn't that the same link you posted before? Anyway, it looks familiar. I have no real knowledge of PDF. I can tell you you don't need Adobe software to add stamps because, if you could, essentially nobody on Linux would be able to use them, but adding stamps is not a problem. I've only ever added them interactively and my viewer doesn't support arbitrary content, so I can't comment on that. But they can also be added non-interactively with CLI tools, for example. I just haven't had any reason to use them. If Linux viewers gain the capacity to display them, creating them might be interesting.

I tried to move this to chat, got a string of nulls, reloaded the page despite the warnings and now there is no such option. Why do SE make things so difficult?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Here is a toy version of some of the functionality I am looking for:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref} % For creating form fields and JavaScript
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\picture@coords{}
\newsavebox{\pushbutton@picture}
\pretocmd{\@PushButton}{\savebox{\pushbutton@picture}{#2}}{}{\errmessage{could not patch \string\@PushButton}}
\pretocmd{\@picture}{\xdef\picture@coords{{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}}{}{\errmessage{could not patch \string\@picture}}
% width, height, Xoffset, Yoffset, name
\newcommand{\PushButtonJSHelper}[5]{
    var x = this.mouseX;
    var y = this.mouseY;
    console.println('Mouse coordinates: (' + x + ', ' + y + ')');
    var obj = this.getField('#5');
    % console.println(obj);
    % for (var key in obj) \string{ if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) \string{ console.println(key + ':' + obj[key]); \string} \string}
    console.println('#5 coordinates: (' + obj.rect + ')');
    var objLowerX = obj.rect[0];
    var objLowerY = obj.rect[3];
    var objUpperX = obj.rect[2];
    var objUpperY = obj.rect[1];
    var objht = objUpperY - objLowerY;
    var objwd = objUpperX - objLowerX;
    var xPercent = (x - objLowerX) / objwd;
    var yPercent = (y - objLowerY) / objht;
    console.println('Scaling: (#1, #2) (#3, #4)');
    var xScaled = xPercent * #1;
    var yScaled = yPercent * #2;
    var xTranslated = xScaled - #3;
    var yTranslated = yScaled - #4;
    console.println('Scaled coordinates: (' + xScaled + ', ' + yScaled + ')');
    this.getField('coordField').value += '\string\\\string\\put(' + xScaled + ', ' + yScaled + ')\string\\n';
}
\newcounter{PushButtonForPicture}
\setcounter{PushButtonForPicture}{0}
\newcommand{\PushButtonForPicture}[2][]{%
    \global\stepcounter{PushButtonForPicture}%
    \PushButton[%
        name=pushButtonForPicture\arabic{PushButtonForPicture},%
        onclick={\expandafter\PushButtonJSHelper\picture@coords{pushButtonForPicture\arabic{PushButtonForPicture}}},%
        #1%
    ]{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

% Define the multiline text field
\TextField[name=coordField, width=300pt, height=100pt, multiline=true]{Mouse Coordinates:}

\PushButtonForPicture{%
\begin{picture}(200, 200)
% Define the button
    \put(0, 0){\makebox(200, 200){Click}}
\end{picture}
}

\end{Form}

\end{document}

I may come back and edit this later to add the other functionality that would make this into an actual editor, such as:

keeping a structured representation of the picture source code in javascript
selecting which \put objects are to be moved using onmousedown or similar (seems like there is currently a bug in hyperref preventing the capture of mousedown events), tracking for each the relative offset of the object to the mouse based on the mouse position when clicking on the object, maybe with a parameter that says "select any object that is close enough to the mouse"
maybe somehow adapting 3D media / media9 to allow dragging of each \put object separately?  Or else having an option to render a grid of hidden copies of the object, and selectively display one on mouse up?


Interesting approach! Unfortunately, the JavaScript Engine of Acrobat does not provide a canvas for drawing onto. Thus, it may be impossible to implement drawing commands for runtime creation of geometric shapes, such as lines, circles, bezier curves etc.
