# LibreOffice + Inkscape EPS-Latex

Tags: svg, inkscape

I'm trying to import a graphic created in LibreOffice Draw in a LaTeX document.

So far I've tried the Way:

1. Export Document to SVG file.
2. Open with Inkscape and Export using eps+latex
3. Including resulting xxx.eps_tex in latex

Although the SVG seems to be just fine (also in Inkscape), the exported positions of the text are bad:

```
\begin{picture}(1,0.73115748)%
   \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{ModeDispersion.eps}}%
   \put(-0.05241193,0.78432034){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Cladding (air)}}}%
   \put(-0.05241193,0.78432034){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Substrate}}}%
   \put(-0.05241193,0.78432034){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{In}}}%
   \put(-0.05472789,0.25830639){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Out}}}%
   \put(-0.05472789,0.25830639){\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{Single-mode}}}%
\end{picture}%
```

and so on. Same for pdf+latex.

Original LibreOffice (version 4.0.1.2) file and exported SVG:
[ODG](http://www.x-linux.de/stackoverflow/ModeDispersion.odg)
[SVG](http://www.x-linux.de/stackoverflow/ModeDispersion.svg)

I can't attach the files created by Inkscape (version 0.48.3.1), as stackoverflow told me that I would need at least ten reputations to do so...

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

edit: Shown in inkscpae:

[image: Inkscape]
<sub>(source: [x-linux.de](http://www.x-linux.de/stackoverflow/ModeDispersion-inkscape.png))</sub>

Processed using latex:

[image: LaTeX]
<sub>(source: [x-linux.de](http://www.x-linux.de/stackoverflow/ModeDispersion-latex.png))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

- The graphics figure Work flow adopted by you `.odg`-->`.svg`--> `eps+tex`/`pdf+tex` is not optimal due to conversion inefficiency of respective editor.
- The [recommended choice of figure format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10970/15717)  is `.pdf` always except for screenshots (`.png`) and photos (`.jpg`) assuming `pdflatex` engine.
- Adopt a 'single' conversion step to generate `figure.pdf`. Either `.svg` to `.pdf` **or** `.odg` to `.pdf` **not** combine them.
- [Inkscape](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions) exports to `.pdf` with latex fonts(latin modern) or close enough, similarly [LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Export_as_PDF#Quality). I have successfully changed the fonts and exported your drawing using Libreoffice to `.pdf`. You can even draw in Inkscape and export to pdf also.

[image]

- But these are not the best approaches for high quality and font consistency with latex text. Read [Why draw diagrams using LaTeX when there are open source tools like OpenOffice?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102590/15717). Select those [vectorial graphic packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597/15717)
  which suits you.

Comment: Ok, it seems that I have no choice but to dig into drawing diagramms directly with LaTeX (what is surely not the worst). I was just curious to know _who_ is guiltily in case of the text items. Is LibreOffice that bad guy who messes around with the svg-standard? I don't think so, because Inkscpae can actually show me the correct image, but export of all texts written in Office is wrong. On the other hand it has really surprised me that text that has been later added directly in inkscpae performs well...

Comment: _Who_ is guilty ? 'Ourselves' for using wrong tools in wrong combination for wrong purpose, when they are best tools in [latex graphic packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/597)

Comment: Ok...I will be looking into pstricks. Thanks. Was just wondering if the svg is wrong or if it is exported badly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you export your drawing as `.png` and the incorporate it like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \pgfimage[width=0.6\textwidth]{myshapes.png}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You will need to use `pdflatex` to compile your `.tex` file.

You can get the whole bunch of files for the above solution [here.](https://sites.google.com/site/stackexchangefilesforothers/home/myshapes.zip?attredirects=0&d=1)

Comment: There are several disadvatages using a PNG-image, as I want everything to be included as vectro graphics. Also Text should be treated by latex itselt, so it will get the same text shape as the rest of the document. Also I mentioned that the filesize is about to explode if I would only use images, as I will need many of them.

Answer (score 0):

When exporting from LibreOffice, the SVG XML gets exported as:

```xml
<svg>
   <text>
      <tspan>
         <tspan>
            <tspan>
            </tspan>
         </tspan>
      </tspan>
   </text>
</svg>
```

The problem is that PDF Export only look coordinate in to text mark.
I just copied the x,y coordinate do text markup.

I made a quick fix using python and I am sharing at gitgub:

https://github.com/thalesmaoa/libreoffice-Calc-SVG-Latex

The result is exactly what I was looking for:

[image]