# Translating Matlab figures into TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab

When ever I want to write a research paper and print the simulated results (by Matlab) into an `.eps` file, I think of a direct way of translating Matlab fig files into LaTeX (especially TikZ).

Is there a way to do such a thing?

Comment: Yes, there is : [http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz)

Comment: I wonder Why would you want to do the conversion vs. just include graphics? Matlab's exportfig  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig experts excellent quality image from Matlab grphics.  What advantage are there to convert it to Tikz and then use that in Latex? Will the result be better than including ps or png in the Latex document? Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser Because the result is far from excellent with matlab.

Comment: @Nasser: just including images does not ensure you to have the same font of the rest of the document; usually, one immediately perceives this difference. That's why if you compare two copies of the same document, one done including pictures, the other done _creating_ pictures with, say, TikZ you will realize _how much the quality differs_. For a more detailed picture, refer to [Why draw diagrams using LaTeX when there are open source tools like OpenOffice?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102590/13304)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in [zuggg's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120131/translating-matlab-figures-into-tikz#comment267663_120131), you can convert MATLAB figures to TikZ by using the [`matlab2tikz`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz) script. What this does is collect the data points and then uses the PGFPlots `\addplot table` to recreate the plot. The author wrote the script so that it also works in [GNU Octave](http://www.octave.org), but the MATLAB Central license does not allow use of the shared software in non-MathWorks products.

Octave, on the other hand, has built-in export capabilities via the `print -dtikz` command. When using the FLTK graphics toolkit, it will generate lower-level PGF commands, and when using Gnuplot, it will generate higher-level TikZ commands. In both cases, the plot is built from basic graphical building blocks (tiny rectangles in some cases) and look inferior to the PGFPlots approach, especially when zoomed in.

Another advantage to the `matlab2tikz` script is that it provides key-value arguments which allow you to do this:

```
matlab2tikz('width', '.8\textwidth')
```

This also shows that you can specify the plot size in terms of TeX sizes. I didn't find a way to do this with the Octave `print` command, and the resulting figures were either too small or too big.