# font in MATLAB figures (type1 / type3)

Tags: fonts, matlab

I have some figures generated in MATLAB. I want to include the figures in a tex file. First I save the figure as eps format. and then I include the **eps** file in the latex.
The default font of the figures in MATLAB is **Helvetica** but after making the Latex file the final PDF file includes type-3 fonts.

Which MATLAB font should I use in my figures that after converting (saving) the figure as **eps** format and including it in the tex file the font becomes type-1 (embedded subset) in the final PDF?

I have checked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78477/matlab-figures-with-latex-fonts), but is there any way to change the default font to some more standard font in MATLAB figure and solve the problem without using any external tools?

I use WinEdt7.0 in windows.

Comment: WinEdt has nothing to do with this. The main question is if the font is embedded into the `eps` or if it is just referred to.

Comment: If you are not absolutely dependent on EPS format, I recommend [`matlab2tikz`](https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz). It exports the MATLAB figure in TikZ/PGFPlots format, so all fonts will exactly match those of the document. See also [these](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120151/21963) [answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153849/21963) of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that since the default font of the figures in MATLAB is Helvetica, if I change the font to Arial after making the Latex file the final PDF file includes only type-1 fonts.

it is possible to use the following lines of code to change the code while producing the figure:

```
set(0,'defaultAxesFontName', '<fontname>')
set(0,'defaultTextFontName', '<fontname>')
```

Comment: It should read as *Helvetica-immitating pixel junk*.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be simpler in the following way. If you use MATLAB eps files  in LATEX, and you use the corresponding pdf file for IEEE conference paper submission you may have this issue. Instead of generating eps file from MATLAB directly, you can generate pdf file from MATLAB, and convert it to eps in the following link:

http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-eps

Then generate pdf file in LATEX. It works very fine, and quality is not compromised as well.

-Jewel