# How to set the size in Octave, using Gnuplot for graphics from Octave?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, gnuplot, octave

I am using Octave for all my calculations and plotting. By telling Octave

```
graphics_toolkit gnuplot
```

I can create a *.tex-document by

```
print -dtikz filename.tex
```

Which I can then use by

```
\input{filename}
```

In combination with

```
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfsys}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Only problem is the size of the graph. During my long path to the above findings, I remember an error message saying that gnuplot uses a standard graph size of 560 by 420 pt. In LaTeX, I usually use something like

```
width = 0.9\textwidth
```

for non-*.tex graphs and I would like my plots to be approximately that large, because I would not like to fumble around with scaling factors or other parameters. That can sometimes mess up the relative positions of the single graphics items.

How do I change the plot size that Gnuplot creates from Octave?

Comment: I recommend [matlab2tikz](https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz), see [my other answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120151/21963) for how to resize.

Answer (score 1):

When using `\input{...}` as a way of including figures made by `Octave` or `gnuplot` you may rescale the image using `\resizebox{x}{y}{\input{...}}`, where `x` and `y` are the required image dimensions in whatever units that you wish. The usage you would like to have requires keeping proportions constant, which would mean typing

```
\resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{\input{plot}}
```

where the `!` fills the missing height to keep the overall proportions constant. This worked throughout my `LaTeX`-aware life. However, this does not necessarily look nice, because the image will not be of appropriate scale: text might be minute, figure illegible, etc. If you wish to instead create the figure to have correct size directly in `Octave`, you should use the [`papersize`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Figure-Properties.html) property:

```
h = figure();

% plot your figure here

set(h, "papersize", [100, 100]);
```

The units used are points. Alternatively, you may use the [`-Sx,y`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html) switch of the `print` command; the two approaches are equivalent, but I think changing the figure properties is more rewarding and definitely more general, hence powerful.

Comment: -Sx,y worked but papersize did not.