# eps images showing mesh?

Tags: eps, matlab

so I created this image in matlab and saved it as an eps-image. And then in latex I compile and build with DVI-PS-PDF-chain, I also use package epstopdf (strange also that the pdf-images (converted from the eps-images) in the latex folder are plank :O, even though the images in the final PDF are okay, other than this).

And image appears like this: It seems to show the mesh also, which I dont want. In matlab when I display the figure, everything is okay.

Do you have any clue why this happens? :)

[image]

Comment: It seems a problem in your Matlab eps creation. Does the eps or pdf file you create by Matlab is fine ? Y-axis is the problem ?

Comment: I havent checked that yet, i'll take a look. no I just took screenshot and cropped it :D both axis show fine. But the image should contain only the color, not the mesh lines which are in white color now :O

Comment: Dude, how are we supposed to see the white color lines ? ;-)
I hope you got your answer.

Comment: haha cant you see the mesh with light white color :D well anyway I got the problem solved. The problem was in the matlab code :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem about your Matlab EPS saving.
I would recommend you to take a look at 
[Translating Matlab figures into TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120131/translating-matlab-figures-into-tikz)
in order to convert your figures in a tikz format, suitable for LaTex.
Also you can check the [Plotting without axes and background](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:eTGET8gxZYMJ:https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/153686&num=1&client=firefox-b-ab&hl=en&gl=ir&strip=1&vwsrc=0)
if you insist to stick to Matlab ploting tools.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens because the eps includes instructions to draw polygons to make up the image, but not their outlines. One way to fix this is as follows:

- Open the eps file in your favourite text editor.
- Look for a line that says something like `/F { fill bind def }` or perhaps
  `/F fill load def` (usually this will be near the top).
- Change `fill` to `gsave fill grestore stroke`.
- Save the file and open it in your eps viewer. The mesh should be gone.

Alternatively, use [polygone](http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~itho17/personal/polygone/index.htm) to remove the mesh and reduce the file size, without reducing the image quality.