# EMF figures in LaTex

Tags: graphics, plot, matlab

I am slowly learning and shifting to latex. Figures I have produced till now are all `.emf` format and now I am unable to load them into latex. Kindly suggest what could be done.

Please do not suggest me to make all plots using Inkscape or GNUPlot, because all of my figures were produced using Matlab and it would be difficult task to reproduce them in other format.

Comment: Try this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120131/translating-matlab-figures-into-tikz

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) EMF is vector graphics. It might be possible to convert them to EPS/PDF. 2) _Print_ them. Use a PS or PDF printer driver to print to file. The optional PS can be converted to PDF. Now you have a PDF, use something like `pdfcrop` to trim the edges, the final PDF is ready for import. Yeah, I now it's not as nice, as a re-plotted `pgfplot`, but it's something.

Comment: What's EMF? ...

Comment: @cfr it's a image file format

Comment: if you still have the matlab sources you could get matlab to print to a more standard format than emf however imagemagic convert which is freely available can convert them eg `emf convert -density "300" file1.emf  file1.jpg`

Comment: @pkj I figured. I wondered what it stood for.