# pgfplot or matplotlib?

Tags: pgfplots, matplotlib

The reason I ask this is because I was trying to draw multiple lines in `pgfplots` (I was trying to make a drawing showing how Riemann sums and integrals are connected). And after unsuccessfully trying to use a for loop for an hour or so, I found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140207/placing-coloured-rectangles-on-a-plot-using-points-from-the-plot-riemann-sums), which was pretty unsatisfying since it's just a workaround for this particular case. And I thought that it would have been much easier with the power of Python. So, my question is: What do I lose by switching to matplotlib?

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your question, but is it not obvious!? -by switching to matplotlib, you loose LaTeX. PGFPlot(in TikZ in LaTeX) is used to create high quality plot outputs.

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen Can't I import the resulting plot into LaTeX anyway?

Comment: Of course, but it's not *generated by LaTeX*.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I know It's not generated by LaTeX. The point is, is there some inherent advantage to drawing all my graphs in LaTeX?

Comment: You get everything in one place, you get the same fonts by default.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Hm, I wouldn't say having everything in one place is an advantage. It'll look much cleaner if drawings don't take half of my code. Plus, changing fonts in matplotlib takes only about two lines.

Comment: Matter of opinion I guess, and there's always `\input`.

Comment: I agree with Torbjørn: the tight integration with the rest of the document is a real advantage for me. It allows for things such as neatly aligning the figures with the rest of the content (scaling to `\textwidth`, for example), or putting the legend in the caption of the figure.

Comment: @Farnight: Maybe open a new question asking how to produce your Riemann sum / integral figure with PGFPlots, showing your PGFPlots attempt and your Matplotlib code. There might be a simple way to do this

Comment: @Jake Alright, thanks. [Here it is](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285249/riemann-sum-graph)

Comment: I see this has been closed now. Anyway, just wanted to mention that it is somwhat similar to [Why draw diagrams using LaTeX when there are open source tools like OpenOffice?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102590)/