# Layout presets for LaTeX Beamer

Tags: beamer

I wonder if somebody was working on slide layout presets for LaTeX Beamer. If you try to create an ordinary slide from scratch most presentation software (e.g. MS PowerPoint) would offer some standard layouts like title slide, two column slide, image slide, multimedia slide etc.

There are many attempts to create two or three column slides, including pictures or not.

My question is if there was a systematic attempt to provide such layout sets for Beamer.

Comment: Not on TeX level, but with the right kind of editors, you could create your own set of presets, see, e.g., http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273659/36296

Comment: Thank you @samcarter I'm using snippets for such tasks. But I was interested if there is a curated collection or kind of library for layouts.

Comment: related question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350734/beamer-consists-of-multiple-frame-layouts