# Beamer consists of multiple frame layouts

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I am creating a beamer that consist of frames using certain layout repeatedly.

To put it simple, let's say my beamer consists of 3 types of frames

- A: only a giant word at the dead centre of the frame
- B: a big pictures with a big (inspirational) word under
- C: a quotation at left, and picture of that person at right

I wish to make some kind of template so that I can later use
`\begin{frame}[A] ... \end{frame}` so that all the setting (font size, colour) are pre-set once and for all, just like MS powerpoint slide layout function.

[image: MS office slide layouts]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174213/36296

The basic idea is to invoke some commands (by loading a special template) if a specific frame option is given. To restrict this to individual frames, the default values are called before every new frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
  \normalsize%
  \normalcolor%
}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{bigword}[true]{%
  \Huge
  \color{orange}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  normal
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[bigword]
  big
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  normal
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more complex "templates", https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257301/36296 could be useful.

Comment: thank you very much, don't worry about the examples (make it big e.g.), I just throw some random needs. The templates layouts are the most important part I wanna solve. :)

Comment: @BaffinChu Did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: I'm so sorry for being a bad member, I was too occupied for these few months. You gave a quick and elegant solution. And I'm terribly sorry for keep you waiting these long months :(

Answer (score 5):

You could try with [`fancyslides`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyslides). It's based on `beamer` but it uses two or three commands to enter predefined formated slides: title, point, itemized (more details in fancyslides documentation). It's also possible to fix a certain background image on every slide.

An example of use adapted from the original distributed with the package is

```
\documentclass{fancyslides} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}

%%% Beamer settings (do not change)
\usetheme{default} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} %no navigation symbols
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=\yourowntexcol} 
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=\yourowntexcol} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% CUSTOMISATIONS %%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%% SLIDE ELEMENTS
\newcommand{\structureopacity}{0.75} %opacity for the structure elements (boxes and dots)
\newcommand{\strcolor}{blue} %elements colour (predefined blue; orange; green)

%%%% TEXT COLOUR
\newcommand{\yourowntexcol}{white}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% TITLE SLIDE DATA %%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\titlephrase}{MAKE YOUR POINT CLEAR WITH FANCYSLIDES}
\newcommand{\name}{Your Name}
\newcommand{\affil}{Company}
\newcommand{\email}{your.email@domain.com}

\begin{document}

\startingslide %this generates titlepage from the data above

\begin{frame}
\pointedsl{Your point}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\framedsl{This is important}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\itemized{
\item BEAMER EASE OF USE
\item MODERN LOOK \& FEEL
}
\end{frame}

\fbckg{frog}
\begin{frame}
\pointedsl{Thank you!}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Finally we can close all the duplicates of this answer!

Comment: @samcarter I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I'm just happy that this question finally has an answer with > 0 votes, which means that now I can vote to close all the unanswered duplicates of this question as duplicate of this question.