# List of "higher-level" Beamer packages

Tags: beamer

I wanted some control over my Beamer slides, so I started reading about how to create a Beamer theme [from scratch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch). However, in the process of doing so I discovered [Metropolis](https://github.com/matze/mtheme), which I regard as a higher-level Beamer package that exposes certain customization level in a simple and well documented interface. It definitely does not provide the same flexibility and level of customization one can achieve by designing a template from scratch, but it is unquestionably much easier to obtain personalized (and beautiful!) slides using this package.

Motivated by this, I wanted to collect a list of other "higher-level" packages that enable a reasonable level of customization while having good documentation. It is my impression (and this is supported by a quick online search) that *Metropolis* is really the only one of this kind, but I would like to ask this community for more pointers in case they exist.

**EDIT:**

I found the following so far:

- [Trigon](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-trigon)

Comment: Well, are you simply looking for non-standard themes? Or what differentiates a “higher-level package” from a theme?

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks for the comment. I do get what you mean, and I also question this myself now that I've been reading more about existing themes. Most of the themes out there expose some interface for simple customization, so I guess I would like a list of these that provide a comparable level of customization (and documentation) as Metropolis. I'm sorry if this is not clear or precise though.

Comment: [fancyslides](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyslides), https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373817/1952