# Picture format eps for LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, pspicture

I would like to create pictures in (`.eps`) format in order to use it with LaTeX, but I do not know which software can be used to create picture in (`.eps`) format.

Comment: While any picture/graphics drawing/creation tool including gimp, dia, xfig, gnuplot, blender, krita, imagemagic can be used to export the image to the eps format, yours is not exactly a LaTeX question. And why stick to only eps format? Other formats like png, jpg, pdf are perfectly good here. Voting to close.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Masroor Please don't vote to close the moment a new user asks a question which doesn't quite fit. Please explain the issue and give the OP some time to improve the question first. (You could at least have welcomed the newcomer, if nothing else.)

Comment: @cfr Forgot to welcome. That is a lapse. But you might have noticed that I provided him enough guideline to choose the software/tool.

Comment: @Masroor It happens ;). I agree the question needs improvement. However, it is not really true that all of those formats are 'perfectly good'. The question specifies LaTeX - not pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX or whatever. If so, then those other formats are *not* 'perfectly good' and, without knowing more, we can't say what the best approach is.

Comment: @cfr Get your point. Retracting the close vote.

Comment: Please take a look at these (http://latexdraw.sourceforge.net/, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents). Then if you have any specific issue please come back and ask. And welcome to TeX.SE (better late than never. :-) )

Comment: @Student, Long time ago it was needed convert images to  EPS files and then run `latex foo.tex` to produce a `foo.dvi` that you can convert in `foo.pdf`. But today, you can use PDF, PNG or JPG images and run  `pdflatex foo.tex`, `xelatex foo.tex` or `lualatex foo.tex` to obtain `foo.pdf `directy. If you use EPS files with these engines, LaTeX will just make a  PDF copy (via `epstopdf`) in order to use it, so just forget about that format, unless you really need make DVI files and not PDF files directly.

Comment: Most people find it more convenient to use pdflatex (which generates pdf output directly) rather than latex (which generates dvi which needs to be converted to pdf later) and if yousing pdflatex then you do _not_ want EPS format as it is not so convenient to import that, you want pdf or png.

Comment: Ow, nobody above have cited *Inkscape* yet. So, it is a good way to draw and export to almost every format.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments.  Please, I have another question when I insert image inside latex it is appear at the top of the page and not in the center and here is the code used: -\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[left=0.5/textwidth,scale=0.6]{GHJ.jpg}
\caption{\label force-length relationship }
\end{center}
\end{figure}

Comment: That's a different question. But don't use the `figure` environment if you don't want the image to float. If you tell LaTeX it is a float, it will allow it to float according to its placement algorithm. So just use the `center` environment. There are packages which will let you use `\caption` outside a float. Just search the site for plenty of examples.