# TikzEdt checking for new version gives "server not found"

Tags: tikz-pgf, editors

Since some weeks ago when I run "Check for updates..." in TikzEdt (version 0.2.3.0 with Windows 10) I get the error:

> Checking for new version failed: Errore del server remoto: (404) Non
>   trovato.

which means "remote server not found".

Is TikzEdt still alive? 
Have I lost the pointer to the site?

Until a couple of month ago all worked well, it gave a message like "there's nothing to update".

Comment: Google shuttered Google Code, which hosted the TikzEdt project, earlier this year. An archive (including the installers and the source) is still available, but the files have been moved to a different domain. In particular, [the URL checked by the update code](https://tikzedt.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/VersionInfo.xml) returns a 404.

Comment: @epimorphic Thank you! Is there a way to get the updates from the new domain? Do you know which is the new one? Is TikzEdt project still alive?

Comment: No updates or code commits for 3 years. I think we can call it dead.

Comment: @epimorphic What a pity! It's so useful!

Comment: @epimorphic Just to _answer the unanswered_, if you would like to post an answer, I'll accept it.