# Putting in picture, getting out TikZ image

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

This is probably impossible; if so, please just say it is. =)

I've done a few drawings/diagrams in TikZ, and I find it very cool, but also a lot of work for a somewhat simple image. However, I do not want to give in to other, worse formats to make a picture. So I was wondering: is it possible to give some program a picture (could be something other than LaTeX), have it get the necessary points from the picture, upload it to LaTeX, and end up with a TikZ picture that at most I have to color (bonus points if it can do that, too).

I  apologize if this is ridiculous (seeing as I'm new to LaTeX/TikZ, it probably is); I can delete it if I'm requested to. I'm just wondering if it's possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you want is more than is reasonably possible.  However, there are gui programs that produce tikz code.  See this [list of such programs.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex)

Comment: Thank you! That will be useful. However, I didn't see any mention of something that carried out what I described (put in a picture, get a TikZ file out, basically). And, I guess, I was also kind of hoping that if it was possible, someone could describe (in a nutshell, I can figure out details) how to do it...

Comment: That's because such a program doesn't exist afaik.

Comment: Um...in your answer you said it was.

Comment: And it doesn't need to be a program; it could be a specific command in a program...

Comment: I said that what you want is more than is reasonably possible.

Comment: Oh, I see, I misunderstood your phrase. Okay, sorry.

Comment: No worries and good luck.