# Dedicated tool for Flow Charts

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I am working on my project that requires many flowcharts and creating everything with `Tikz` package will take a lot of my time. There is one Java-based tool `LetexDraw` that I use for diagrams, and I know about `TikzEd` which also prepares diagrams in Tikz. but is there any tool or web-based tool that is designed for the flow charts only or easy to prepare flow charts?
Currently, I am preparing my flowcharts using `tikz` following is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
% processes
\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Input};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {Process 1};
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=pro1,yshift=-0.5cm] {Decision 1};
\node (pro2a) [process, below of=dec1, yshift=-0.5cm] {Process 2adsjksdjfksdjfksdfjksd};
\node (pro2b) [process, right of=dec1, xshift=2cm] {Process 2b};
\node (out1) [io, below of=pro2a] {Output};
\node (stop) [startstop, below of=out1] {Stop};
%arrows
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (pro2a);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (pro2b);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=east] {yes} (pro2a);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=south] {no} (pro2b);
\draw [arrow] (pro2b) |- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro2a) -- (out1);
\draw [arrow] (out1) -- (stop);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Flow chart for Code} \label{fig:flchart}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This is the format that I am using, I have followed steps provided on sharelatex, Problem with this code is I cannot center it properly. when I have bigger boxes in place and have multiple stages in the same line.

** P.S.
I have figured out the problem and I could manage to Get Good Looking Flowcharts but my problem is it takes a lot of time to arrange the nodes and arrows the way I want. I have to modify the shifts every time I edit steps in between, So, I was just asking that if there are any tools such as TikzEd which will reduce the efforts for making flowcharts
**

Comment: drawing of flowchart is relative simple. if you prepare `\tikzset` dedicated for drawing them (typically between four and five elements) and in drawing use libraries `calc` chains` and `positioning` for placing of flowchart elements, they drawing will go fast. on drawing you can look on as brain exercise :-). learning also require some time and results is not so satisfactory as classical manual drawing. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: The diagram you show is centered properly. I can only guess that you run into problems if the diagram becomes wider than `\textwidth`, in which case the usual thing happens: it goes into the right margin. (This is no different from a wide table, for example.) So then you need to either make the diagram narrower, or do something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39436

Comment: Could you show us your problematic lines with "bigger boxes"..., which you can't add?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What GUI applications are there to assist in generating graphics for TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex)