# Auxiliary drawing tools

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, tikz-3dplot

I am a beginner, drawing with tikz is a bit difficult for me. 
Is there an auxiliary drawing tool that is suitable for beginners?
Especially drawing three-dimensional graphics.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please look at this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex

Comment: I found this useful: http://www.tikzedt.org/. It is not complete and some advanced functionality sometimes do not work, but it is perfect to experiment and go back and forth between graphical and code sides.