# Using a 2D Toroid in Circuit Diagrams

Tags: circuitikz

I’m trying to replicate the 2D Torus in the picture shown below using CircuiTikZ [image]
The other questions in this TeX Exchange have created 3D models of toroids which I don’t which to have since I want it to be added to the circuit that I have. Is there a way to add a compatible command of a 2D toroid so I can add it to diagrams?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us some short compileable TeX code you have tried so far? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Where have you taken your picture in the web? CircuiTikZ have not toroid symbol.

Comment: @2above I don’t have much code that I have at the moment because I’m very new in learning how to start and add new circuit macros to an already existing CircuiTikZ package. I’m not that comfortable with making them but I can use TikZ to create diagrams.

Comment: @above I have gotten this diagram from problem 88 here https://www.ioc.ee/~kalda/ipho/electricity-circuits.pdf

Comment: It can be done with an external program with the fonts CM. I have not found zero information on CircuiTikZ and in pst-circ.

Comment: That kind of toroid is not a circuit symbol --- it's more a physical drawing of a toroidal transformer. So  I feel it's not in the scope of `circuitikz`; it's nice, yes, but it's more a generic drawing than a symbolic circuit representation. That said, you can draw the rest of the circuit with `circuitikz`, no problem.

Comment: @Rmano I have seen this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex I didn't find anything. In my opinion it is generated by an external program.

Comment: The drawing is not made with `circuitikz`,  I am quite sure @Sebastiano - look at the joining of the wires with the ammeter, they are not symmetrical and the wire stems out.

Comment: @Rmano Acute spirit of observation. Even I have seen, before, that the line crosses the ammeter by a few millimetres. :-):-) And the simbol of the tilde of V is very strange.

Comment: Hm, what do you guys think this diagram was generated with then? Is it perhaps a mix of multiple languages?

Comment: My guess is that it has been drawn with a drawing program by hand, but I can't be sure. Anyway, with a bit of strategy, you can draw the toroid in Ti*k*Z for sure --- but I have no time in hands now to try, sorry. A couple of circle and then a foreach on a spline (look at `.. controls () and () ... ` in the manual) should do it.

Comment: If you really want to draw this, may i suggest you create a pic for a single wrap of the coil.  It will run much faster.