# a quick way to add graph and sketches to lyx

Tags: graphics, lyx

I'm looking for a **quick** way to add simple graphs and sketches to lyx. for example showing the graph of sin or drawing excircles of a triangle (shown below).
is there such a tool out there?

[image][image]

Comment: for the sin curve --pgfplots-- for the excircle -- tkz-euclide

Comment: are they quick? is there a tool like paint, that I can quickly draw in but will be more exact?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex