# Tikz-euclide in TikzEdt

Tags: tkz-euclide

I used tikz-euclide in tikzEdt.
However, when I reinstalled my computer, I couldn't use it anymore.
Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Unfortunately, TikzEdt is no more maintained, I'm afraid you should search for another editor. See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex.

Comment: You need to change settings in TikzEdt : in Settings > Compiler, add "\usepackage{tkz-euclide}" and then regenerate precompiled headers.

Comment: Thank you. I changed in setting but it not work!