# Difficult Spiro Para-Hexagonal Ring?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, graphs, chemfig, tikz-shape

How can I draw the following diagram in LaTeX?  [image]

this is code but it is different,

```
 \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4,cap=round,>=latex]
\draw[thick,blue] (0,0) -- (2,1.5) (2,1.5) -- (4.5,1.5) (4.5,1.5) -- (6.5,0) (6.5,0) -- (8.5,1.5) (8.5,1.5) -- (11,1.5) (11,1.5) -- (13,0) (16,0) -- (18,1.5) (18,1.5) -- (20.5,1.5) ;
\draw[thick,red] (0,0) -- (2,-1.5) (2,-1.5) -- (4.5,-1.5) (4.5,-1.5) -- (6.5,-0) (6.5,0) -- (8.5,-1.5) (8.5,-1.5) -- (11,-1.5) (11,-1.5) -- (13,0) (16,0) -- (18,-1.5) (18,-1.5) -- (20.5,-1.5) ;
\filldraw[black](14,0) circle(4pt);\filldraw[black](14.5,0) circle(4pt);\filldraw[black](15,0) circle(4pt);
\filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](0,0) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](2,1.5) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](4.5,1.5) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](6.5,0) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](8.5,1.5) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](11,1.5) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](13,0) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](16,0) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](18,1.5) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](20.5,1.5) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](2,-1.5) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](4.5,-1.5) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](8.5,-1.5) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](11,-1.5) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](18,-1.5) circle(7pt);
 \filldraw[fill=black,draw=black](20.5,-1.5) circle(7pt);
\node[above] at(2,1.5) {\tiny$1$};
\node[above] at(4.5,1.5) {\tiny$2$};
\node[above] at(8.5,1.5) {\tiny$3$};
\node[above] at(11,1.5) {\tiny$4$};
\node[above] at (18,1.5) {\tiny$2n-1$};
\node[above] at(20.5,1.5) {\tiny$2n$};
\node[below] at(2,-1.6) {\tiny$\check{1}$};
\node[below] at(4.5,-1.6) {\tiny$\check{2}$};
\node[below] at(8.5,-1.6) {\tiny$\check{3}$};
\node[below] at(11,-1.6) {\tiny$\check{4}$};
\node[below] at (18,-1.6) {\tiny$\check{(2n-1)}$};
\node[below] at(20.5,-1.6) {\tiny$\check{(2n)}$};
\node[above] at(0,0) {\tiny$1^0$};
\node[above] at(6.5,0) {\tiny$2^0$};
\node[above] at(13,0) {\tiny$3^0$};
\node[above] at(16,0) {\tiny$n^0$};
 \draw [thick, blue] (0,0) to[out=-120,in=100] (0,0) to[out=-220,in=20] (20.5,1.5);
\draw [thick, red] (0,0) to[out=120,in=00] (0,0) to[out=220,in=-20] (20.5,-1.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure} { spiro para-hexagonal cylinder chain}\label{fg1}
  \end{center}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Right now, this is just a do-it-for-me which may well get closed. If you've got some code you've tried and can explain the particular problem you're having, you're more likely to get help.

Comment: I make it, but it is different, this is code

Comment: You got a great deal of help in response to your previous do-it-for-me (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/685563/). That should enable you to make a start here. If you just don't want to learn Ti*k*Z or similar (and why should you?), there's no reason you should, but you need a better strategy than posting do-it-for-mes on this site. Essentially, you either hire somebody to do your diagrams on a professional basis or you use one of the many GUI tools, which typically have gentler learning curves than Ti*k*Z et al. If your goal is to learn, people here will help, but you have to do the hard work.

Comment: If you spend some time with the tutorials recommended to you last time, this is really not at all difficult: just some circles and lines. Use polar coordinates to help with the positioning.

Answer (score 4):

I would use polar coordinates (as suggested by cfr in the comments) and loops probably to reproduce the above. Also, I would use nodes for the small circles.

Something like this could serve as a starting point (but it probably needs further tweaking):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={
        circle,
        draw, 
        inner sep=1.5pt
    },
    invisible/.style={
        draw=none
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,3} {
        \pgfmathparse{(\i == 0 ? "" : "invisible")}
        \node[\pgfmathresult] at ({45*\i}:2.125) (A-\i) {};
        \node at ({15+45*\i}:2.5) (B-\i) {};
        \node at ({30+45*\i}:2.5) (C-\i) {};
        \node at ({10+45*\i}:1.5) (b-\i) {};
        \node at ({35+45*\i}:1.5) (c-\i) {};
        \node at ({45+45*\i}:2.125) (D-\i) {};
        \draw (A-\i) -- (B-\i) -- (C-\i) -- (D-\i);
        \draw (A-\i) -- (b-\i) -- (c-\i) -- (D-\i);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I can't really make out the labels and adding those might need to be done separately
but here is a `graphs`-powered solution with its [`grid placement`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#pgf./tikz/graphs/grid:placement).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard, ext.misc}
\tikzgraphsset{
  between from/.initial=, between target/.initial=,
  between/.style args={#1 and #2}{between from={#1}, between target={#2}},
  grid width/.initial=2, grid height/.initial=2,
  grid size/.style args={#1x#2}{grid height={#1}, grid width={#2}},
  declare={subgraph grid between}{
   [/utils/exec=% a bit math and short macros
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\gDist{% distance between the nodes in the grid between
        distancebetween("\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/graphs/between from}",%
                        "\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/graphs/between target}")/%
                        (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/graphs/grid width}+1)}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\gAngle{%
        anglebetween("\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/graphs/between from}",%
                     "\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/graphs/between target}")},
    wrap after=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/graphs/grid width},
    group shift=(\gAngle:\gDist),
    chain shift=(\gAngle+90:\gDist),
    /tikz/shift=(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/graphs/between from}),
    /tikz/shift={([rotate=\gAngle]\gDist,%
                  {-\gDist/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/graphs/grid height})})},
    grid placement,
   ] subgraph I_n
  }
}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \graph[
    nodes={shape=circle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+1ex, draw}, empty nodes,
    radius=3cm,
  ]{
    subgraph I_n[name=main, V={0, ..., 5}, clockwise=10, phase=180],
    \foreach[count=\i from 0]\j in {1, ..., 5}{
      subgraph grid between[name=between \i_\j_,% don't want to deal with \space
                         between={main \i} and main \j,
                               V={1, ..., 4}],
      main \i -- {between \i_\j_ 1, between \i_\j_ 2}
              -- {between \i_\j_ 3, between \i_\j_ 4} -- main \j
    },
  };
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: We could also make the grid size dependent on the number of nodes (`\tikzgraphVnum` = 4) but here, you define the grid size yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For chemists, Spiro rings are easy to make with ChemFig

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setchemfig{bond join=true}
    \chemfig{*6([:-30]---(*6([0]---(*6([0]------))---))---)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A 3D simulation is not difficult to obtain

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\setchemfig{bond join=true,atom sep =2em,cram width =3pt,cram dash width =0.2pt,cram dash sep =0.4pt}
    \chemfig{*6([:-30]---(<[:330]-[,,,,,line width=3pt,shorten <=-.5pt,shorten >=-.5pt]>[:30])(-[:30]--[:330])---)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With a little more work it is possible to make more complex structures.