# Is there any tool to convert a circuit diagram to circuitikz latex code?

Tags: diagrams, circuitikz

I'm looking for software that can convert a circuit jpg/png file to Circuitikz (Latex) codes, just like the [image2latex-matrix](https://github.com/blaisewang/img2latex-mathpix) tool.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome! I know none (I am the maintainer of `circuitikz`).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex, and also https://hackaday.io/project/170745-circuitikz-tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a *very* difficult task, although I understand that the software that does the same with formulas can help. Circuits geometry can be very complex, and extracting the structure from a pixmap is not trivial.

So the answer is: ***No, not at this time.***

You can try some [GUI approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex?noredirect=1&lq=1), but again, there is little of it specifically though for outputting a decent `circuitikz` code.