best tool with easy positioning for drawing electrical circuits?
Last year I tried learning to use circuiTikz which proved rather difficult with the school year simultaneously, so this year I'm looking for a simpler tool for drawing circuits, preferably ones that can be converted to tikz code, most online tools I've looked for had either a small library of components (not having dependant sources, writing with formatting like underscore, etc...)
yesterday I found out about the circuit_macros package, which sounds promising but looks technical and difficult and such isn't what I'm looking for.
so I'm asking here if others may have found a better alternative, it's important that it'll be something that can be easily learned almost intuitive so my time will be spent efficiently on solving circuits instead of drawing them (haha)
thanks in advance for any help, for those wondering I'm using LyX on a Windows 10 laptop, and I'm an Electrical Engineer Student.

maybe you can find something in this list: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex

More specific, look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730224/38080 --- this generates circuitikz code. The tool is progressing rapidly. It is also commented in recent circuititz manual.

@Rmano thank! this is almost perfect, missing some small features but I think I can overcome these
