# Is there any tool to draw bezier curve and transfer the coordinates to tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there any tool to draw bezier curve graphically.

Using the  coordinates in the tool, can we draw bezier curve in tikz?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82308/replacement-for-curveto-in-the-tikz-library-inkscape-export-svg-to-tikz) and [this?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/better-way-to-calculate-coordinates-in-tikz/1240#1240)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz Also: http://texample.net/tikz/resources/#tools-that-generate-pgftikz-code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Option -- 1

You can use [TikzEdt](http://www.tikzedt.org/). It has two windows, one for tikz code and the other for picture. Right click on the figure window to get a list of possible options as in this picture:

[image]

Select `Bazier path` and then you can plot a bazier path using mouse clicks:

[image]

You will get the `tikz` code on the left window automatically.

Comment: Option--2 and option--3 have been hijacked by Karl's students `;-)

Comment: I intentionally left the first option for you.

Answer (score 4):

It is too long as a comment.

You can use [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) or [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/).

I took some notes from GeoGebra as follows.

Release Notes GeoGebra 3.2:

> in SVG and PDF export, option to export text as editable text or
>   shapes. Stores the text either as text (lets you edit the text in eg
>   InkScape) or as bezier curves (ie guaranteed to look the same even if
>   the correct font is not installed).

and

> PGF/TikZ export

With [`inkscape2tikz`](https://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/) one can export drawings from Inkscape as TikZ code.

Comment: How was your original post too long for a comment? Anyways, you can throw in a link to [`inkscape2tikz`](http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/), as well as links to Inkscape and Geogebra, to make it more of an answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes it is too long for a comment while I was preparing the complete answer. Thank you for the link.